# Is it possible to you convert privkey to BIP39 mnemonic (or entropy)?

Tags: private-key, mnemonic-seed, vanitygen

I've generated a private key using [`vanitygen` command](https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus) by:

```
$ ./vanitygen 11
Difficulty: 256
Pattern: 11                                                                    
Address: 114beUkusDnzqxif5BbESZMNo6T5N27...
Privkey: 5JeApQGQCCEp1K3rjXr8vDcEWMFw2Agzj2YZnN51zZC37Sw7...
```

Is it possible to convert a generated Privkey to BIP39 mnemonic words or entropy (hex)?

As the app/wallet which I'm using only accept BIP39 mnemonic words to import a wallet and I would like to create a wallet using a `vanitygen` utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I know this isn't possible.

The mnemonic phrase is hashed to get a seed number. Hashing algorithms are one-way algorithms.

See [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki)

> To create a binary seed from the mnemonic, we use the PBKDF2 function with a mnemonic sentence (in UTF-8 NFKD) used as the password and the string "mnemonic" + passphrase (again in UTF-8 NFKD) used as the salt. The iteration count is set to 2048 and HMAC-SHA512 is used as the pseudo-random function. The length of the derived key is 512 bits (= 64 bytes).

> This seed can be later used to generate deterministic wallets using BIP-0032 or similar methods.

---

Related:

[is PBKDF2 reversible?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77513/52982)